# creating spark dataframe of .dat.gz file present in aws s3 using aws glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have written one pyspark code which is running in aws glue and trying to read one dat.gz file. dataframe is getting created successfully but `Trim(BOTH FROM)` is getting added to the column name. Below is my code snippet.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 'false').option("delimiter", '|').load("s3://xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx.dat.gz")
```

output

---

```
+----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|Trim(BOTH FROM EFF_DT)|Trim(BOTH FROM SITE_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM ARTCL_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM SL_UOM_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM COND_TY_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM EXP_DT)|Trim(BOTH FROM COND_REC_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM MAIN_SCAN_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_COND_PRRTY_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_COND_WIN_IND)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_RSN_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_METH_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_AMT)|Trim(BOTH FROM PRC_QTY)|Trim(BOTH FROM UT_PRC_AMT)|Trim(BOTH FROM PROMO_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM BNS_BUY_NUM)|Trim(BOTH FROM CURRN_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM BBY_TY_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM BBY_AMT)|Trim(BOTH FROM BBY_PCT)|Trim(BOTH FROM BBY_LEV_CD)|Trim(BOTH FROM BBY_PRC_QTY)|
+----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--
```

But when reading any other file, I am getting the correct output.
Can anyone help me on this?
This is not a file problem because I tried the same code in my local machine and it is running fine.

Comment: How are you adding column names when header is set to false

Comment: sorry.. It was my mistake. it is header is true  and still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you mind to share sample test data file? To be honest, it shouldn't be adding anything to column name

Comment: Got the issue. BOM marks( ï»¿) is appearing in the file.But not able to find the solution, how to create dataframe properly

Comment: If `Trim(BOTH FROM)` is consistent, you can rename columns after reading data.

Comment: @BasantJain Can you post the sample data here?